# Shared script does not execute

Tags: python, windows, shared

A .pyw script to present a small GUI (TkInter) to the user. From a Windows Server Terminal server, it does not run for others.

I wrote a .pyw script to present a small GUI (TkInter) to the user. On my windows desktop, with Python installed, it runs well. I uploaded the script to a Windows Server Terminal server, from where I want a number of users to run it. I can run it when I log onto the terminal server. Other users, however, cannot run it, and it does not display any error messages.

I have ensured that everyone on the server has full access to the script.

The code is running perfectly

Comment: Is Python installed for all users and accessible to them? And if they're running via the .pyw file association, is that properly configured for all users?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... This was rather simpler than I thought.

Because it is a .pyw file, an error did not show up. I did not make use of Python's errror catching tools.